# How to implement the adaptive Heun's method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to implement code for [Heun's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method) function in python. But I'm also doing it in the adaptive style. Regularly for say rectangle method, if you do adaptive style, you compare the area from `a` to `b`, with the sum of `a` to the center of `a` and `b` and then from that center to `b`. If its the same with a tolerance, then return the sum, if not, then recurse on both intervals.

This is what I got so far:

```
import math

def k(x,y):
    return math.sin(x+y)

''' h is the step size '''
def Heun(f,x,y,h,end):
    while x < end:
        f0=f(x,y)
        z=y+h*f0
        x+=h
        f1=f(x,z)
        y+=h*0.5*(f0+f1)
    return y 

def AdaptDiff(diffF,f,x,y,h,end,tol):
    if abs(1.-x/end) < tol:
        return y
    y1=diffF(f,x,y,1,x+h)
    y_=diffF(f,x,y,1,x+h/2.)
    y2=diffF(f,x+h/2.,y_,1,x+h)
    if abs(1.-y1/y2) > tol:
        return AdaptDiff(diffF,f,x+h/2.,y2,h/2.,end,tol)
    return AdaptDiff(diffF,f,x+h,y1,h*2.,end,tol)

print AdaptDiff(Heun,k,0,1,1/2.,1,1e-10)
```

But I'm getting a maximum recursion depth exceeded error. Does anyone know whats wrong here? I should be getting `1.73513792333`.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling diffF with 1 in the place of the step size h? In the current philosphy you should call `y1=diffF(f,x,y,h,end)` and `y2=diffF(f,x,y,h/2,end)`. Think about making this iterative and reusing the already computed values. Take note that if h is too small, the error will increase due to accumulation of floating point noise.

Comment: For another implementation, with Arenstorf orbits as a test case,
see ODE12-adaptive-stepsize
under [gist.github.com/denis-bz](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz) .

Answer (score 3):

### On theoretical lower accuracy bounds for order 2 methods

Heun is a second order method, that means that the global error is of second order and the local discretization error is of size 
$$
|y_n(t_n+h)-y_n(t_n)-h·\Phi_f(t_n,y_n(t_n),h)|=C\cdot h^3,
$$ 
where $y_n(t)$ solves the IVP $y_n'=f(t,y_n)$, $y_n(t_n)=y_n$. To be measurable, this must not exceed the machine precision $\mu\sim 10^{-16}$, so $h\sim 10^{-5}$ is the lowest step size where the order behaves numerically as theoretically.

The estimate of the global error has the form and size
$$
C·T·h^2+\frac{D·T·\mu}{h}\ge 3·T·\left(\frac14·C·(D·μ)^2\right)^{\frac13},
\qquad\text{"=“ for }h=\left(\frac{D·\mu}{2·C}\right)^{\frac13}.
$$
The second term stands for the accumulation of floating point errors of about $D·μ$ in each step and over $N=T/h$ steps (a more correct factor instead of $N$ for longer time intervals is $(e^{LT}-1)/(Lh)$ with the Lipschitz constant $L$).

This is a convex function in $h$ with a minimum and thus gives the limit for any realistic tolerance prescription.
Assuming the constants $C,D,T$ all have the magnitude $1$, the lower limit is about $tol=10^{-10}$ with a step size of again $h=10^{-5}$. With a prescription of $tol=10^{-12}$, the number $N=10^6$ of steps is guaranteed to lead to an accumulation of floating point errors of size $10^{-10}$ at least, thus preventing to reach this tolerance.

---

### On ways to have a correct adaptive scheme

The following corrects your python code to a version where $h$ is fixed for the full integration interval and adapted over several integration runs so that the relative error in the end is between tol/4 and tol. This is the closest variant to your code, but probably not what was originally intended. The original intend may have been to adapt the value of $h$ for each Heun step, but one would have to more radically change your code to achieve that.

In iterating once for step size $h$ giving the value $y_1$ and once with $h/$ to get $y_2$, one gets $y_1=y^*+C·h^2+O(h^3)$ and $y_2=y^*+\frac14C·h^2+O(h^3)$. This can be used to compute better approximations for the error term and the exact value
$$
y^*=\frac{4·y_2-y_1}3+O(h^3),\quad y_1-y^*=\frac43(y_1-y_2)+O(h^3),\quad y_2-y^*=\frac13(y_2-y_1)+O(h^3)
$$

```
import math

def f(x,y):
    return math.sin(x+y)

''' h is the step size '''
def Heun(f,x,y,h,end):
    while x < end:
        # floating point error may make x over- or undershoot end
        if x+h>=end:
            h=end-x
        k0=f(x,y)
        k1=f(x+h,y+h*k0)
        x+=h
        y+=h*0.5*(k0+k1)
    return y 

def AdaptDiff(diffF,f,x,y,h,end,tol):
    # print debugging information on the recursion level
    print "called with h=",h
    if abs(1.-x/end) < tol:
        return y
    # integrate the full interval, 
    # once with step size h and once with h/2
    y1=diffF(f,x,y,h,end)
    y2=diffF(f,x,y,h/2.0,end)
    # print debugging information on the approximations found
    print "y1=%.15f, y2=%.15f, y1-y2=%.4e, y*=%.15f" % ( y1, y2, y1-y2, (4*y2-y1)/3 );
    # if relative error is too large, decrease step size
    err = abs(1.-y1/y2)/3;
    if err > tol:
        while err > tol/2: 
            h   /= 2.; err /= 4.
        return AdaptDiff(diffF,f,x,y,h,end,tol)
    # if relative error is far too small, increase step size
    # but this will rarely happen
    if err < tol/64:
        return AdaptDiff(diffF,f,x,y,h*4.,end,tol)
    # return the last computed value, might also return y2
    return (4*y2-y1)/3

x0=0; y0=1; xe=1; 
tol = 1e-10; h=(tol/(xe-x0))**0.5;

print "returned %.16f" % AdaptDiff(Heun,f,x0,y0,h,xe,tol)
```

This recursion finishes in one step, i.e., with two integration runs with step sizes `h= 1e-05` and `h/2= 5e-06` for the objective `tol=1e-10`:

```
called with h= 1e-05
y1=1.801069211924622, y2=1.801069211940325, y1-y2=-1.5703e-11, y*=1.801069211945559
returned 1.8010692119455591
```